# In python, (0, 1, 2000000) < (0, 3, 4) = True, why?

Tags: python-2.7, comparison, tuples

I tried 2000000 < 4 and (2000000,) < (4,) but these are returning false.

But why the (0, 1, 2000000) < (0, 3, 4) is returning true even though 2000000 is greater then 4

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of corresponding elements.
>
> If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first differing elements. For example, cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y]) returns the same as cmp(x,y).

So in `(0, 1, 2000000) < (0, 3, 4)`, the first pair of elements match, so the second pair are compared.  Since 1 is less than 3, the entire thing is `True`, and the remaining elements need not be evaluated at all.

This is basically the same ordering used in a phone book, just generalized from characters to any types.

If you want a fast comparison of all elements, you can use NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
np.all(np.array((0, 1, 2000000)) < np.array((0, 3, 4)))
```

This gives `False` as it's doing a logical AND of the vectorized comparison results.

Comment: So, for any relational operator it skips the initial set of values in the sequences until it finds unequal elements, then will consider those unequal elements for comparison. Am I right?

Comment: Right.  This is known as "lexicographical comparison."